# Android - Local Video Presentation

Tags: android, video, local, presentation

I need to create a "presentation" that will run on android devices.
Essentially, this needs to be a full screen background video loop, with two floating containers that display an animation until one of them is clicked.  When clicked, the container then displays a video inside it and when the video finishes it returns to the animation.

I already did this as an online web page, but as the presentation needs to be displayed on android devices at an exhibition which has not internet connection, I need to try and do this locally.

Initially, I thought this would be simply a matter of changing video codecs, but alas, no.

This is such a simple thing that is proving to be quite hard.
Can anyone offer any suggestions please.

Comment: I have been reading various posts, including some on SO too, which is confusing matters more.

Not looking to build an app as I did not want to have to get involved with coding, HTML and CSS is about my limit, so I don't want to have to use Webview.

Initially thought that this could be done by having the video stored locally and then run an html page in Chrome, but seems that codecs would be an issue.

A presentation in 2010 worked, but then ran into issues with the the small videos going full screen, then needing a player for Android.

Now not sure, what path to take to try and achieve this